# Creating trigger before delete mysql

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064, database-trigger

I have two tables, `car_ride` and `car_ride_saved`.

```
car_ride                                 car_ride_saved
id |  person | car | start |          id | person | car | start | saved
```

Before i delete row in `car_ride` i want that row to saved in `car_ride_saved`.

I decided to handle this on database level - i decided to create a trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_car_ride_delete 
    BEFORE DELETE ON car_ride
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO car_ride_saved (
        person, car, start, saved
    ) VALUES(
        OLD.person, OLD.car, OLD.start, NOW()
    );
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

However this complains about syntax error. I am running mysql 8 and (or) 5.6.

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) in both version syntax shoul be correct (if i havent overlooked some detail ).

the error is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'person, start, car, saved
    ) VALUES(
        OLD.person, OLD.car, OLD.start , NOW()
' at line 6
```

What is causing the problem here?
Thanks for help!

Comment: And the error message is....?

Comment: @Uueerdo oh sorry i forgot to add it... updated question

Comment: Yeah, that looks fine; maybe try to check for weird non-printing characters between `person` and the `(` preceding it? _Or try deleting `(...p` and retyping it._

Comment: Also, `start` is a reserved work, not delimiting it with `` could maybe cause some issues; but I'd have thought the "near" would reference it then.

Comment: i have tried to create same trigger for other tables with basic names ( no reserved keywords ) and the error remained the same, the escaping shouldnt be problem

Comment: The syntax is correct. I did copy & paste of your trigger statement and tested it with MySQL 5.6.37. No error. I am guessing @Uueerdo is correct, you have some invalid nonprinting characters in there.

Comment: @Darlyn What are you using to execute these trigger creates?

Comment: @Uueerdo i am using phpmyadmin console, i have fixed the problem, apparently the tables did not have set autoincrement on ID, setting it solved my problem.